# Is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^4}{1+t^6} dt$ convergent?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Question: Is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^4}{1+t^6} dt$ convergent?

Try: I am trying to apply limit compression test but I am  unable to decide ..

Comment: this integral is convergent and the result is $$\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: @SG: How? Can you tell me bit more? Thanks

Comment: For integrals of the form 

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^m}{t^n+1}\,dt$$

You can always use the Beta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. A potential problem is as $ t \to \infty$, but one may observe that
$$
0\le\frac{t^4}{1+t^6}\le \frac{1}{t^2}, \qquad t\ge1,
$$ giving the convergence of the given integral by comparison to a Riemann integral
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^\alpha}<\infty,\qquad \alpha>1.
$$